# How can I check the contents of folders for certain files?

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

How would I go about writing a script to loop through every folder on a hard drive, find any video files, extract them to the root of the hard drive, and then delete everything else?

Comment: Use `find`, and in particular its `-exec` switch. Match file names via `-iregex` or `-iname`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, if you need to "loop" over a set of files in Linux, you don't want to write an actual Bash loop (e.g. with `for`), but use `find` instead. The following should work for all versions of `find`, and Linux distributions come with GNU `find`, [whose manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html) you should definitely read at some point.

Be careful with the following commands. If you don't know what you're doing or don't check the results first, you *could* irreversibly lose data.

```
find /mount/drive -type f  \( -iname "*.mp4" -o -iname "*.avi" \) \
-exec echo mv '{}' /mount/drive/ \;
```

This would print a list of `mv` commands. Once you're sure it does what you want, remove the `echo` from the command and execute it again.

Note:

- `-type f` will restrict the results to only files.
- `find` will overwrite files with the same name without a warning. To avoid collisions, use `mv -i`, which would prompt you in such a case.
- You can add more conditions to this to search for other file types, e.g. `-o -iname "*.mov"` et cetera.

---

In a second step, we will delete everything that's not in the root of the drive. To do so, we need two commands, since you first want to delete all the files …

```
find /mount/drive -mindepth 2 -type f
```

Once you're sure this lists everything you want to delete, add `-delete` to the command. Here, `mindepth 2` ensures that your root (with all the videos in it) stays untouched.

Then, find the remaining empty folders:

```
find /mount/drive -mindepth 1 -depth -type d -empty
```

Similar to above, add `-delete` to this command to actually delete the empty directories.

Comment: Fantastic answer, the best I've ever gotten on StackExchange. Thanks so much.

Comment: This'll find folders named '...avi' as well IIRC. Also, will this work with 2+ files found? IIRC we discussed this recently with arguments after `{}`.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks, you're right. the `-type f` applies to both only if you group the conditions. With regard to moving and multiple arguments, etc., it only works with GNU `find` (and GNU Coreutils `mv`), but `find … -exec mv -t /mount/drive '{}' \+` should do the trick.